# Does Kosher for Passover imply kosher all year round?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover

Many products say "Kosher for Passover and all year round".  Isn't "kosher for Passover" also automatically kosher year round?

Comment: We had this question already, can't find it at the moment, can someone else look for a minute?

Comment: Please give the answer if you remember it.

Comment: Matzah isn't permitted on the day before Pesach.

Comment: Many years ago, a relative of mine was traveling to Canada after Pesach  and passed through a town in upstate NY for mincha. The rabbi saw him and asked him to do a favor and sit in fit him for 20 min in his office to answer phone questions. Being a Bachur he was hesitant s he was unsure if he’d be able to answer. The rabbi assured him it will be fine. The first caller asked if something that is kosher for Passover can be eaten after Passover. (He then realized he would be able to answer). Perhaps they’re trying to clarify for those who don’t know

Answer (score 1):

For food, yes. For some medications and cosmetics, there are is a [guide](https://www.eichlers.com/rabbi-bess-star-k-pesach-guide-2022-ibsla211.html) that checks for chametz but not overall kashrus. (Whether or not you need to have these be kosher for Passover is a CYLOR issue.)

Answer (score -7):

Technically something could be treif but kasher lipesach. The labeling is a bit superfluous because non-kosher products aren't usually made kosher lipesach.

Comment: Please explain how this is 'technically' possible.

Comment: kasher lipesach just means there is no chametz in it, so if you have a big mac in between 2 peices of matzah it can be kasher lipesach, but not kosher.

Comment: @KovyJacob klp involves not just being chometz-free, but also being kosher. A whole spit-roasted suckling pig contains not one iota of chometz, but is not kosher period, let alone kosher for passover

Comment: Legabay the inyan of chametz its kasher.

Comment: I'm coming over!!

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Okay?

Comment: This is incorrect. I can't imagine any kashrut agency that would label a non-kosher product "kasher l'pesach"

Comment: @JohnSmith If you ate a piece of of pork on Pesach you would not be chayiv for eating chametz. You would not get an issur kares of eating chametz on Pesach.

Comment: @JohnSmith I can explain it to you but I can't understand it for you. If you eat pork on Pesach YOU DO NOT GET KARES FOR THE LAV OF EATING CHAMETZ ON PESACH. Although it is treif, if is kasher lipesach.

Comment: We are discussing kasher lipesach, not kosher in general. There are 2 issurim: to eat treif, and to eat chametz on pesach. It is possible to only transgress on eating treif, but not on eating chametz on pesach.

Comment: Kasher lipesach means something that you can eat on Pesach without transgressing the prohibition of eating chametz on Pesach. If you eat pork, you will not be transgressing the prohbition of eatingchametz on Pesach.

Comment: @KovyJacob That's not what most people mean when they say that something is "kosher l'Pesach". Instead, they mean "I can eat this on Pesach". This is presumably also what the original post intended, and why you have many downvotes.

Comment: @magicker72 The question is 'Isn't "kosher for Passover" also automatically kosher year round?', so I said that technically no, something can be kasher lipesach but not all year round. It is 2 seperate things.

Comment: @KovyJacob But you assumed a meaning of "kosher for Passover" that was unintended. If you change the definition of words, you can say anything you want, but your answer is also useless to the OP.

Comment: @Magicker72 Questioner: 'Isn't "kosher for Passover" also automatically kosher year round?', Me: 'No'.

Comment: @KovyJacob "kosher for Passover" = "kosher" ∩ "contains no chametz" ≠ "contains no chametz".

Comment: @magicker72 There are 2 issurim at hand: 1) the issur of eating non-kosher, and 2) the issur of eating chametz on pesach. So, for example, if you ate pork on Pesach you would transgress the issur of eating treif, but you would not transgress the issur of eating chametz on Pesach. Hence, it is not kosher, yet it is still kasher lipesach.

Comment: @KovyJacob You're saying things, but they aren't responding to my comment. Anyone else can read these comments and figure out what's going on.

Comment: @magicker72 I understand, I'm just not sure I agree.